# why did't work one controller function route in same controller functions in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have three TaskController function methods like this in My laravel application,

```
  public function show($project_id,$task_id)

     {
        $project = Project::find($project_id);
        $task = Task::find($task_id);
    view('tasks.show')->withProject($project)->withFiles($files)->withTask($task);
 return view('tasks.show', ['task' => $task, 'project' => $project]);
     }
    public function show1($project_id,$task_id)
      {
        $project = Project::find($project_id);
        $task = Task::find($task_id);
view('tasks.show')->withProject($project)->withFiles($files)->withTask($task);
       return view('tasks.show1', ['task' => $task, 'project' => $project]);
     }
    public function show2($project_id,$task_id)
     {
        $project = Project::find($project_id);
        $task = Task::find($task_id);
view('tasks.show')->withProject($project)->withFiles($files)->withTask($task);
   return view('tasks.show2', ['task' => $task, 'project' => $project]);
     }
```

and my routes for this is like this,

```
Route::get('projects/{projects}/tasks/{tasks}',[
'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\TasksController@show',
    ]);
Route::get('collaborators/projects/{projects}/tasks/{tasks}', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\TasksController@show1',
   ]);

Route::get('collaborators/projects/{projects}/tasks/{tasks}', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\TasksController@show2',
  ]);
```

but among above three routes **show1** route is not working. but if I delete **show2** route then show1 is working. how can I fix this problem?

Comment: that is because they have the same url. what are you trying to achieve like that

Comment: I need redirect different pages according to user permissions

Comment: then write that logic in the controller

Comment: **show** and **show2** are working with properly problem with show1 it is working as show function here

Comment: that is because show1 and show2 have the same url.

Comment: how can I write logic here

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot help you write logic for your application because only you know what you want to achieve.

Comment: ok then if I change url is it woring?

Comment: yes it is working with different url thanks @JoshKisb